# How to check sign using javascript and php , Like this?

Tags: javascript, php

How to check sign using javascript and php , Like this ?

First, user will fill data in to input `username` and `password`

If `username` and `password` correct, It's will be alert `SUCCESS`

But `username` or `password` incorrect, It's will be alert `FAIL`

I tested my code, But not work. How can i do that ?

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" id="sign_in_fid">
    <label>
        Your Username
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <br> 
    <label>
        Your Password
    </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <br>       
    <br> 
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in"/>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkform ( form )
{
  var username_val = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password_val = document.getElementById("password").value;         
</script>


<?PHP
    include("connect.php");
    $strUsername = "<script>document.writeln(username_val);</script>";
    $strPassword = "<script>document.writeln(password_val);</script>";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM av8_users WHERE BINARY username = '$strUsername' and password = '$strPassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $active=$row['active'];
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1)
        {
?>
            <script>
            alert("SUCCESS");
            </script>
<?PHP
        }
    else 
        {
?>
            <script>
            alert("FAIL");
            </script>
<?PHP
        }
?>
<script>
return true ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your script is very vulnerable to attack. Dont use mysql, use mysqli  and look up and use prepared statements. You are setting a post submit type in your form but then not using it. You need to go back to basics.

Comment: You should put this on CodeReview rather than StackOverflow. There are multiple fundamental issues with your code.

Answer (score -1):

The reason your code is failing is you are using JavaScript inside php code.
Try changing your

```
$strUsername = "<script>document.writeln(username_val);</script>";
$strPassword = "<script>document.writeln(password_val);</script>";
```

To

```
$strUsername = $_POST['username'];
$strPassword = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: You should be making some attempt at sanitising the posted data before using it.

Comment: @Matt Holbrook, yes, but this was just a indication to the mistake robert was making.